# VALORES DE UN CASE EN VARIABLES MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo este codigo, pero no me funciona. Lo que quiero es meter el valor del case en una variable y esa variable tendrá un valor u otro dependiendo del valor del parámetro de entrada

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION fn_diabreviado (IN diasemana varchar(15)) RETURNS CHAR(1) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE diaabreviado char(1);

SELECT CASE 
WHEN diasemana='Monday' THEN SELECT 'M' INTO diaabreviado
WHEN diasemana='Tuesday' THEN SELECT 'T' INTO diaabreviado
WHEN diasemana='Wednesday' THEN SELECT 'W' INTO diaabreviado
WHEN diasemana='Thursday' THEN SELECT 'H'  INTO diaabreviado
WHEN diasemana='Friday' THEN SELECT 'F'  INTO diaabreviado
WHEN diasemana='Saturday' THEN SELECT 'A' INTO diaabreviado
WHEN diasemana='Sunday' THEN SELECT 'S' INTO diaabreviado
END;

RETURN diaabreviado;

END //
```

Comment: has probado con if condiicon then .... elseif condicion  then ... ect

Comment: No, pero más que nada porque me habían dicho que un case es más óptimo que usar if elseif

Comment: Si es mas optimo pero menos lógico, luego cuesta comprenderlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varias cosas:

1. No tienes que poner en cada `CASE` la instrucción `THEN SELECT 'laLetra' INTO diaabreviado` indica cada `CASE ... WHEN` sin más, poniendo el `INTO` sólo al final.
2. Si estás declarando una `FUNCTION` no tienes que indicar el tipo de parámetro, si es `IN` en este caso. En las funciones los parámetros **siempre son reconocidos como del tipo `IN`**, a diferencia de las `PROCEDURE`, que son las que aceptan diferentes tipos de parámetro. [El MR es claro en esto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html):

> Note
>
> Specifying a parameter as `IN`, `OUT`, or `INOUT` is valid only for a
> `PROCEDURE`. For a `FUNCTION`, parameters are always regarded as `IN`
> parameters.

De este modo debería funcionar:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_diabreviado;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION  fn_diabreviado (diasemana varchar(15)) RETURNS CHAR(1) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE diaabreviado char(1);
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN diasemana='Monday'    THEN 'M' 
        WHEN diasemana='Tuesday'   THEN 'T' 
        WHEN diasemana='Wednesday' THEN 'W' 
        WHEN diasemana='Thursday'  THEN 'H'  
        WHEN diasemana='Friday'    THEN 'F'  
        WHEN diasemana='Saturday'  THEN 'A' 
        WHEN diasemana='Sunday'    THEN 'S' 
    END 
    INTO diaabreviado;

    RETURN diaabreviado;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

### Control de nulos

Si quieres evitar los nulos desde la función, puedes poner esto al final de los `CASE`:

```
ELSE ''
```

Algo así:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN diasemana='Monday'    THEN 'M' 
    WHEN diasemana='Tuesday'   THEN 'T' 
    WHEN diasemana='Wednesday' THEN 'W' 
    WHEN diasemana='Thursday'  THEN 'H'  
    WHEN diasemana='Friday'    THEN 'F'  
    WHEN diasemana='Saturday'  THEN 'A' 
    WHEN diasemana='Sunday'    THEN 'S' 
    ELSE ''
END 
INTO diaabreviado;
```

Sin el `ELSE`, cuando pases un día que no esté en los `CASE` te retornará `null` y con el `ELSE` te retornará una cadena vacía. Aplica lo que mejor te convenga según el contexto.

### Fiddle

Te dejo un fiddle completo como prueba:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_diabreviado;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION  fn_diabreviado (diasemana varchar(15)) RETURNS CHAR(1) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE diaabreviado char(1);
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN diasemana='Monday'    THEN 'M' 
        WHEN diasemana='Tuesday'   THEN 'T' 
        WHEN diasemana='Wednesday' THEN 'W' 
        WHEN diasemana='Thursday'  THEN 'H'  
        WHEN diasemana='Friday'    THEN 'F'  
        WHEN diasemana='Saturday'  THEN 'A' 
        WHEN diasemana='Sunday'    THEN 'S' 
    END 
    INTO diaabreviado;

    RETURN diaabreviado;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT fn_diabreviado('Monday');
```

| fn_diabreviado('Monday') |
| --- |
| M |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT fn_diabreviado('Tuesday');
```

| fn_diabreviado('Tuesday') |
| --- |
| T |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3EqgYcAL3TKeGCYXoVNLMB/2)

Comment: muy buena respuesta +1 yo esta como tenia lo mismo pero me falta el ``INTO diaabreviado;``

Comment: Gracias @JavierG.Raya. Saludos.

Comment: En un rato añadire otra respuesta con if elseif @A.Cedano

Comment: A mi me funciona su codigo  @Adrián

Comment: Si si totalmente. Fallo mio

Answer (score 1):

Yo en lugar de usar **CASE** lo haría es la estructura `IF ELSEIF` el cual te puede resultar mas fácil de entender y realizar :

***1.*** Añado el `DROP FUNCION IF EXISTS` por si acaso

***2.*** Guardo en la variable `diaabreviado` la letra con un `SET` el cal es mas común

***3.*** Te faltaba poner un delimitador al final `DELIMITER ;`

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_diabreviado $$
CREATE FUNCTION fn_diabreviado (diasemana varchar(15)) 
RETURNS CHAR(1) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE diaabreviado CHAR(1) DEFAULT '';

    IF (diasemana='Monday') THEN
        SET diaabreviado = 'M';
    ELSEIF (diasemana='Tuesday') THEN
        SET diaabreviado = 'T';
    ELSEIF (diasemana='Wednesday') THEN
        SET diaabreviado = 'W';
    ELSEIF (diasemana='Thursday') THEN
        SET diaabreviado = 'H';
    ELSEIF (diasemana='Friday') THEN
        SET diaabreviado = 'F';
    ELSEIF (diasemana='Saturday') THEN
        SET diaabreviado = 'A';
    ELSEIF (diasemana='Sunday') THEN
        SET diaabreviado = 'S';
    END IF;

    RETURN diaabreviado;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Por ejemplo si ejecutamos la función :**

```
SELECT fn_diabreviado('Sunday');
```

nos devolverá `S`

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/273)

Comment: Gracias por la aportación :))

Comment: de nada amigo :)

Comment: Javier, en realidad `CASE ... WHEN` es menos verboso, más claro y más sencillo, además es más conforme al estándar SQL.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias @A.Cedano pero prefiero esta estructura porque nunca he usado un CASE en mysql

Comment: Entiendo, pero ten en cuenta que `CASE ... WHEN` es parte del estándar SQL y que `IF` puede no funcionar en algunos SGBD, mientras que `CASE ... WHEN` sí funcionará en todos. Esto es importante, sobre todo a la hora de migrar de un SGBD a otro.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias @A.Cedano lo tengo en cuenta para la próxima vez , le echaré un ojo 